# How can I write multiple files using for loop?

Tags: python, file, for-loop, beautifulsoup

Hi I want to create files with name file1.txt, file2.txt, ... etc. I am getting limit error for it. What do I need to do in my code to make it work?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('reut2-000.sgm', 'r')
data= f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

contents = soup.findAll('body')
for i, content in contents:
    file = open("file%i.txt" %i,'w')
    file.write(content.text)
    file.close()
```

I am getting `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack` error. and when I give loop for i inside I get error `IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'file508.txt'`

Comment: What is a limit error? Is that `[` a typo? It might be the problem

Comment: Post specific error message.  An OS will typically have a limit on number of open file handles.  It's possible (though I wouldn't expect) that `del file` in your loop would help.

Comment: I'd expect a `SyntaxError` here - are you trying to write each result of the body to a new file each time?

Comment: @jasper It was typo. I am getting 'ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack' error. and when I give loop for i inside I get error 'IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'file508.txt' '

Comment: @DummyGuy: use the [edit] link to add that information to your question.  You will need to review the currently-pending edit, though.

Comment: @DummyGuy are you sure you don't have `enumerate()` call there? `for i, content in enumerate(contents):`

Comment: @alecxe It worked with enumerate(). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

The `contents` in your case would contain a list of [`bs4.Tag`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag) instances. If you want to "index" them - use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, content in enumerate(contents):
    file = open("file%i.txt" % i,'w')
    file.write(content.text)
    file.close()
```